How to configure ElasticSearch with JavaScript to return only exact matches for search queries?
I have a search option in my ElasticSearch UI search kit project, and I need it to show results based exactly on what the user searches. Currently, if a user searches for "DRAD", the results include "FRDA", "RAD", "DA", "ADR", and other partial matches. However, I want the search engine to return only the exact match for the keyword.
search setting configuration 
search_settings: {

        highlight_attributes: ["title"],
        snippet_attributes: ["content", "date"],
        search_attributes: [{ field: "title", weight: 3 }, "content", "tags"],
        result_attributes: ["title", "url", "tags", "date"],
        facet_attributes: [{
            field: "tags",
            type: "string",
            attribute: "tags"
        }],
        

      const search = instantsearch({
        indexName : '',
        
        searchClient: SearchkitInstantsearchClient(sk),
        
        })
        
        
        `serach box setup`

      search.addWidgets([
     instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
          container: "#searchbox",
          searchAsYouType: true,
          //queryType: 'prefixNone',
           searchablePlaceholder: 'Search Here',
        }),

